# Appended html always added to last dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append an input field and a button to a dynamically created div with an id. Everytime another button is clicked, `var i` increases by one, that number is added to the id I am trying to append my HTMl to.

```js
// Category
var i = 1;
$('#addcategory').click(function() {
  i++;
  $('#dynamic_field').append('<div class="row" id="row' + i + '"><div class="col-md-8"><ul class="categorylist"><li><input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="' + i + '. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list" /><div id="dynamic_questionfield' + i + '"><div class="row" id=questionrow"' + i + '">  <div class="col-md-8"> <ul class="questionlist">  <li> <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list" />  </li> </ul>  </div>  <div class="col-md-4"> <button type="button" name="addquestion" id="addquestion' + i + '" class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>  </div> </div></div></li></ul></div><div class="col-md-4"><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></div></div>');
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
});

// Question
var e = 1;
$(document).on("click", "#addquestion" + i + "", function() {
  e++;
  $('#dynamic_questionfield' + i + '').append('<div class="row" id="questionrow' + e + '"> <div class="col-md-8"> <ul class="questionlist"> <li> <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="' + e + '. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list"> </li> </ul> </div><div class="col-md-4"><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + e + '" class="btn btn-danger removequestion btn_removequestion">X</button></div></div>');
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn_removequestion', function() {
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#questionrow' + button_id + '').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic_field">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <ul class="categorylist">
        <li>
          <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list" />
          <div id="dynamic_questionfield1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <ul class="questionlist">
                  <li>
                    <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list" />
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="button" name="addquestion" id="addquestion1" class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" name="addcategory" id="addcategory" class="btn btn-success">Extra categorie</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a screenshot of what I mean:

When I click the first button that says `extra vraag` it should add an extra input field in the first list but it adds it to the second.

[image]

The same happens if I add multiple lists, it always adds the new input field to the last listitem added.

Why is that?

[image]

Comment: This is the wrong approach. `$(document).on("click","#addquestion"+i, ...` will not work like you think it does, it only adds a handler to the element referenced by whatever `i` happens to be when that line runs. Don't use `id`s with added numbers. jQuery has lots of helper functions like `.closest()` or `.find()` you can use. The general idea is to add a generic button click handler that goes up the HTML tree to the appropriate parent, then adds the required fields to the appropriate child.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you, is there an example of this somewhere?

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/wyce8dmv/

Comment: @ChrisG Great, thank you. This code even changes numbers when a field is deleted!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the script below. When you click the extra vaarg button targeting class "questionbutton" it will add an additional row element based on your current html structure.

$(document).ready(function(){
    var new_input = `<div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <ul class="questionlist">
                  <li>
                    <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list" />
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="button" name="addquestion" id="addquestion1" class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
              </div>
            </div>`;

```
$(".questionbutton").on('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().append(new_input);
});
```

});